# Why does the Anderson-Hsiao adjustment pick the twice-lagged first difference?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, autocorrelation, dynamic-regression

My understanding is that the Anderson-Hsiao adjustment, described [here as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqwDcY9pq5I), addresses concerns about potential or actual autocorrelation by taking a first difference of the dependent variable and adding an independent instrument which happens to be the twice lagged first difference of the dependent variable.

My question is: Why doesn't this adjustment continue to permit correlation with the once lagged first difference? If this occurs in every period, isn't that a failed correction for autocorrelation?

Comment: pretty good answer here on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/gejtrb/q_clarifying_the_andersonhsiao_estimator/